# Python subprocess command line error

Tags: python, time, command-line

I am so confused. So I'm trying to use my program `program10.py` which uses another program, for example `other_program`

So I might run it like this:

```
python3 program10.py other_program
```

The `other_program` accepts one int argument
Here is my `program10.py` code:

```
import time
import subprocess
n = 2**10
myList = []
while n <= 2**15:
    before = time.process_time()
    subprocess.call(n)
    after = time.process_time()
    print(n, after-before)
    myList.append(after-before)
    n *= 2

print(myList)
```

And of course I get this big error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program10.py", line 7, in <module>
    subprocess.call(n)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 557, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I have no doubt that I am using subprocess.call completely wrong, because I don't understand it, and none of the other SO questions or the Python docs helped me out. If anyone could please tell me how it relates to my program, that would mean a lot.

Comment: The first time through your loop, you try to execute `subprocess.call(2**10)`.  The second time would be `subprocess.call(2**11)`.  What Python is expecting there is the *name* of the program to execute; perhaps `sys.argv[1]` for the command-line parameter passed to your program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the name of the program that you are trying to run in `subprocess.call()`. The error says an `int` is not iterable. Iterables are objects like strings, lists, or tuples. They're an object that "contains" several items, and can return those items one at a time.  `subprocess.call()` usually requires a list containing the command and any arguments that you want to run. For example:

`subprocess.call(['other_program', str(n)])`

But this will only return the return code of the program. If you need any of the output that the program creates, you're going to need to use a different function like `subprocess.check_output()`

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to find the amount of time it takes to run that executable within my program. Which is why I use the time before and after, but it seems that no matter what code I use, and no matter how big my integer value is, it takes the same amount of time. It isn't supposed to do this. It's supposed to take more time the bigger the data is. Is there something else I am doing wrong? I changed my subprocess statement to this: `subprocess.call(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: You are probably not passing the `n` value to the program. Try this:

`subprocess.call([sys.argv[1], n])`

Comment: hmmm that had no effect.

Comment: Are you sure `sys.argv[1]` has the name of the other program you want to call and the OS knows how to run it from your current location?

Comment: if you launch the program outside of Python: `other_program 1024` and `other_program 32768`, Does the second one take longer than the first one? Even better, try: `time other_program 1024` and `time other_program 32768`

Comment: That should be `subprocess.call([sys.argv[1], str(n)])` - it should have given an error if passing an int as a parameter.

Comment: @calico_ and @ jason ok now I am getting a different kind of error. I am testing it with a program that I know takes about 4 times a long as the data size doubles. It definitely is taking much longer every time it's going through powers of 2, but I am still outputting around 0.0007 seconds every time. I must be using the time module wrong. How can I make it output the time it takes for the subprocess code to execute?

Comment: Yes! `time.process_time()` returns the amount of processor time that your program has used. Try using `time.time()` which just returns the system time in seconds since epoch.

Answer (score 1):

The line "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" tells you that the function expects an iterable, not an integer. Try passing a string or a list of strings.